# Undefined variable error php even after variable is set

Tags: php, session, fat-free-framework

I have defined a variable $userStatus globally in a class, and the value is to be overridden [when a option is selected in drop-down]. The variable is overridden by a session value that is set when the drop-down is changed.
When the session is not set, the function is working fine.. but when the drop-down is changed and the session is set, Undefined variable $userStatus is displayed. 
Here is what I tried:

```
protected $userStatus = 1;

public function export($f3, $params)
{
    if(null !== ($this->f3->get('SESSION.userStatus')))
    {
        $this->$userStatus =  $this->f3->get('SESSION.userStatus');
    }
    $rowID = 5;
    foreach ($results as $result) 
       {
          if($this->userStatus == 2)
             {
                //logic
             }
          else{ //.... }
          $rowID++;
       }
}
```

Here's how the session is set with ajax:

```
public function updateUserStatus($f3)
    {
        $status = $this->f3->get('POST.status');
        $this->f3->set('SESSION.userStatus', $status);
        echo $status;
    }
```

NOTE:

- export function is run with default $userStatus value.
- when the value is changed, session is set and $userStatus value is supposed to be overridden
- now when the user clicks "Export" button, the export function is run again, with the session value set. that's when the variable is unrecognized.

I just wanted to set a default value for $userStatus, otherwise, it is working fine when the dropdown is changed. Please where did I do wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a typo.

**Change from this**

```
$this->$userStatus
```

**With this:**

```
$this->userStatus
```

**Also change this**

```
if(null !== ($this->f3->get('SESSION.userStatus')))
```

**With this:**

```
if(!empty($this->f3->get('SESSION.userStatus')))
```

Comment: I'm ashamed right now... :D... thanks for pointing that out :)